How to force multiple midi parts to play in chorus for same notes?
I have written down the saxophone parts for an upcoming concert for practice in lilypond. The output should be pdf as well as midi. Everything works fine, except for one part, where one of the saxphones seems to play a note into the rest. After searching my mistake for quite some time I think the issue is not a wrong note. Midi seems to play same notes in different parts as a "single instrument that plays louder". I actually had this issue before between 1st and 2nd alto sax, but there it didn't matter as much, since the tenor plays something different there.
Here is the parts output from lilypond:

The note in question is the last note in the 4th measure. Is there a way to force same notes to be played as chorus?

Lilypond is probably playing the note once but doubling the velocity.

@PiedPiper it is not doubling the velocity, but the volume as described in the post. The question is, how to force it to play the same note for each different instrument, so that it sounds like multiple instruments?

As I understand, Lilypond is not aiming for overly refined audio output. But as a workaround, maybe you can assign a different midiInstrument to one of the staves? See e.g. this list https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/midi-instruments there are several types of saxophones and also other similarly sounding instruments

@user1079505 yes seems like it - so far I have only used the actual instruments, so tenor and alto saxophone.

I suspect, this may be a psychological effect: the notes are played, but you don't hear them as separate. Different real-world instruments  and players never reach exactly the same soundwave. A sensible intermediate step might be, to open the midi file in a DAW and assign different stereo positions to the respective voices.

The "into the rest" part of this is odd. Is there reverb? I fail to see why the unison should create a perception of longer duration, aside from reverb.

Do you want a midi file specifically, or just some type of audio file to go with the PDF score?

Which program are you using to play the MIDI file?

@ElementsInSpace I tried two different pieces of software. Started with FluidSynth and also tested out VLC player. I have the whole project setup in VSCODE, where I have written a python script, which will call Lilypond via shell producing the PDF and MIDI files. After that the script will call VLC without GUI to transcode the midi file into an MP3 output. For this i have set up Arachno_SoundFont_Version_1.0.sf2 for midi playback in VLC.

To get this to sound right, there needs to be seperate samples for each of the different instruments.
This is because playing a particular sample through two different channels simultaneously will sound like single instrument playing louder.  (Or, as Laurence’s answer mentions, if there is some minute offset in the timing, you’ll get phase effects.)
Fortunately, there are MIDI instruments for both alto and tenor saxophone (as well as soprano and baritone), but in your case, you’ll really want two different sample sets for each of the altos.

As well as the various MIDI instruments, LilyPond can apply several MIDI effects including: Pan, Balance, Expression, Reverb, and Chorus.  But whether or not the MIDI player is listening for these effects, or if it has a way to implement them, will depend on the particular software you are using.  (There might even only be one sample set for all four types of saxophone.)
I suggest trying out something like placing \set Staff.midiChorusLevel = #1.0 in one (or both, or all) of the staves before that unison note, and reverting after.  See if this helps — I can’t try it out myself, as the MIDI player that I use doesn’t seem to know what to do with Chorus Level.
Another option to try might be to change the MIDI instrument to some other similar instrument for that note (e.g. Saxophone 1 could switch from alto to soprano).

Oh, thank you. I did not know these controls are available. I will try this out :)

On the last beat of bar 4 all three saxophones have the same note.  It's quite possible that your playback system is allocating three instances of exactly the same sample to these three notes.
If the system renders them perfectly simultaneously, you'll just get one extra loud note.  But it won't.  Not quite.  So you'll get all the nasty phase effects that happen when three identical waveforms are played ALMOST in perfect synch.  Maybe a 'hollow' sound.  Maybe something pulsating.  Maybe even a false extra pitch.
Some playback systems are clever enough to allocate slightly different sounds to Alto Sax 1, Alto Sax 2 and Tenor Sax.   If yours isn't, it's a good idea to disable playback of two out of the three instruments when they coincide in unison.  It won't sound like three players on the same note, but it will sound a lot better than the alternative!
Saxophone ensembles played by general-purpose sound sets always sound like a fairground organ anyway.  Use playback to check you've scored the right notes.  Be happy that in the concert it will be played by real instruments!
